# Why doesn't my ball spin? - lua - corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, geometry

I made this code:

```
ballImage = "ballImage.png"
    circle = display.newImage( ballImage, {x=_W/2, y=_H*0.885}) 
    circle.width = _W*0.06
    circle.height = _W*0.06
    circle.type = "circle"
    physics.addBody( circle ,{radius=_W*0.030} )
```

When it collides or falls it isn't spinning but always remains straight . (But it moves and reacts to clashes)
Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess: try to specify some friction, if there is no friction, ball should not rotate after collision. See https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/physics/physicsBodies/index.html for the exact way to specify it.

EDIT: Per @JLONG's comment, specify friction explicitly.

Comment: I just tried it without declaration of "Friction". It won't rotate when it is not declared as 0.3 on the parameters.